# R: feglm dummy coding

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, fixest

I´m trying to run fixed effects regressions in R using the **feglm** command from the **fixest package**.
The data contains three dummy variables: (1) variable z is 0, (2) variable z is between 1 and 8, and (3) variable z is larger than 8. I understand that it is necessary to drop one dummy to avoid collinearity. However, is this done by feglm or do I have to do it manually?

The question boils down to whether I have to include 2 or 3 dummies in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The manual describes a `feglm` parameter `collin.tol`:

> **collin.tol**
> Numeric scalar, default is 1e-10. Threshold deciding when variables should be
> considered collinear and subsequently removed from the estimation. Higher values
> means more variables will be removed (if there is presence of collinearity). One
> signal of presence of collinearity is t-stats that are extremely low (for instance
> when t-stats < 1e-3).

... so you will have to increase `collin.tol` to make `feglm` drop variables for collinearity "on its own accord" (unless their respective [t-statistic](https://www.statology.org/t-test-linear-regression/) were indeed even smaller than the [catch-all default](https://www.statology.org/t-score-p-value-calculator/) 1e-10).